# ASP Panel not showing after click

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, panel

So, I have a list on the side and each of those supposedly are showing and displaying a panel when clicked on. But the last module I programmed just kinda refresh the page but does nothing, doesnt show the panel but all of the others are showing the panel without issues.

Heres a little bit of the section of the code.

```
    <tr id="trShare">
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgShare" runat="server" ImageUrl ="Images/share.png" width="22px" height="22px" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShare" runat="server" Text="Share..." ></asp:LinkButton> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

<tr id="trEmail">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ="Images/share.png" width="22px" height="22px" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmail" runat="server" Text="Email Contact" ></asp:LinkButton> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
<asp:Panel ID="panelShare" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopUp">
        <h2>Share this applicant</h2>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>
            <p>An email will be sent with a link to this page.  Please add a valid username.  Only @asf.edu.mx are allowed.</p>
            <p> <asp:TextBox ID="txtShareWith" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>@asf.edu.mx </p>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:Button  ID="btnCancelShare" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnShare" runat="server" Text="Share"  CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnShare_Click" />
            </div>
        </blockquote>           
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelEmail" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopUp">
        <h2>Share this applicant</h2>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>
            <p>An email will be sent with a link to this page.  Please add a valid username.  Only @asf.edu.mx are allowed.</p>
            <p> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>@asf.edu.mx </p>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Share"  CausesValidation="false" />
            </div>
        </blockquote>           
    </asp:Panel>

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender4" runat="server"
        PopupControlID="panelEmail" 
        TargetControlID="lnkEmail"
        CancelControlID="btnCancelEmail"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackGround" 
        DropShadow="true" ></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
        PopupControlID="panelShare" 
        TargetControlID="lnkShare"
        CancelControlID="btnCancelShare"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackGround" 
        DropShadow="true" ></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The Email section is the one that is not showing....at all.

Comment: Add a `</table>` above `<asp:Panel ID="panelShare" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopUp">`?

Comment: Well, apparently I just copied the parts of a working part and the parts of the one that is not working... Should I add the whole code? Since it does have the<table> and such... Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. The button `btnCancelEmail` does not exist inside Panel `panelEmail`.

Change

```
<asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Into

```
<asp:Button  ID="btnCancelEmail" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
```

Comment: This was just plain stupid haha didnt know I had to fill all the params. Well Thank you very very much, sir.